# one element, one event, one alert, one click, 4 messages

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="galerina.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="galerina">
            <img class="img1" src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="img2" src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="img3" src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="img4" src="images/4.jpg" alt=""/>
            <p/>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="galerina.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.galerina{
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

div.galerina img{
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.galerina img.galerina1, div.galerina img.bullet{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
/* Find each div with class galerina */
$("div.galerina").each(function(){
    var gal=$(this);
    var size=$(gal).children("img").size();
    var i=0;
    /* Find each img tag inside the div */
    $(gal).children("img").each(function(){
        var img=$(this);
        /* Append an image to the gal and show an alert */
        $(gal).append("<img src='images/bullet.png'/>").click(function(){
            alert('test');
        });
    });
});
```

clicking on bullet makes 4 test alerts popup??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused about what `$(gal).append()` returns, it returns `$(gal)` not the thing that was appended. So, when you say this:

```
$(gal).append("<img src='images/bullet.png'/>").click(function() { /* ... */ });
```

You are adding a click handler to `$(gal)` and you do that once every time you go through the loop so you end up with four identical click handlers. I think you want something more like this:

```
var $img = $('<img src="images/bullet.png"/>');
$img.click(function() { alert('test'); });
$(gal).append($img);
```

That will put the click handler on the appended image rather than on `$(gal)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've said that `alert('test')` should be called for each of the `img` children in `div.galerina`. I've edited the formatting of your question to help you see why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

By using event delegation you can avoid the headache of binding a click handler to each image:

```
$("div.galerina").delegate("img", "click", function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/xz9dD/)

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/